# URL Rewriting after redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, url, subdomain, rename

I've managed to have .htaccess redirect some of my domains to subdomains. Now i'd like to change the title of the urls. Or to put it differently, change how the url appears on screen in the url input of the browser, but i just can't seem to get it to work. I must've overlooked something.

I'd like it to be so that it won't show http://subdomain.domain.com/, but just http://www.subdomain.com/. *And I do own the necessary domains*.

My current code:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub1\.com$ [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^ http://sub1.domain.com [R,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub2\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://sub2.domain.com [R,L]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://sub1.com/$1 [redirect,last]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://sub2.com/$1 [redirect,last]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me! Unfortunately it didn't work. Sub1 is going to the correct subdomain but is still showing where it's going and Sub2 is, for some odd reason, going to the main domain.

Comment: The name did stay sub2.com though... Maybe it somehow didn't redirect, but just rename?